# ionic2 reset inputs,textarea value after submit

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a form in `AddMedicine.html`, as you can see I call a function `addMedicine()` in `AddMedicine.ts` when the button is clicked and do is actions.

GitHub:
https://github.com/eshk12/Parabi/tree/DB-LINKED

Html page with the form:
https://github.com/eshk12/Parabi/blob/DB-LINKED/src/pages/AddMedicine/AddMedicine.html

After the action succsess, I want the `Inputs` and the `Textarea` will reset.
how can I do that?

I have saw many guides how to do that but I did not understand which classes I really need to import, and how to use it.

Thx for your help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to reset the fields of your model to blank values. The inputs that are bound to these model values will update accordingly to the model.

In your case:

```
MedicineName = '';
// continue for all your model properties you want to reset: MedicinePrice, InjectionRate...
```

I believe this should happen in the then of your call to the persist the data:

```
this.networkServices.CreateMedicine(obj).then(() => {
    this.MedicineName = '';
    // ...
});
```

I also see that in your module.ts you are missing:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

NgModel does not work without this angular module.

### Note

This is possible because angular uses the MVVM pattern (Model View View Model). I strongly recommend to read about this before coding any serious angular application:

> MVVM – Model-View-View Model
>
> MVVM is a refinement of the MVC design and the ViewModel in MVVM is
>   used for the simplification of Presentation Separation. In the MVVM,
>   the logic is stored in the presenter and the View is completely
>   isolated from the Model. While the presenter isn’t aware of the View,
>   the View is aware of the presenter – the presenter in MVVM is used to
>   represent an abstract view of the user interface. A passive view means
>   that the View doesn’t have any knowledge of the Model. In the MVVM
>   design pattern, the View is active and contains behaviors, events and
>   data binding information. Note that the view in MVVM is not
>   responsible for managing the state information – the view is rather
>   synchronized with the View Model. The ViewModel in MVVM is responsible
>   for presentation separation and exposes methods and commands to manage
>   the state of a view and manipulate the Model.

Comment: @itzikb sorry, try it with `this.MedicineName = '';`

Comment: @itzikb I also edited my answer because you are missing `FormModule`

Comment: I didnt have any use for FormModule, do i need to add something else?
and it still dont work..

Comment: @itzikb NgModel depends on FromModule, it won't work if you don't add this module to your app.
I guess if you don't have this module, your code is not passing the `if` statement that check the inputted values as the model is not updated from the template if NgModel is not working. Please confirm.

Comment: I dont know, its still dont work i update the code on GitHub u can see

Comment: @itzikb in /src/app/app.module.ts, line 2, add `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131193/discussion-between-piou-and-itzikb).